# Event handler doesn't work anymore after html rerendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following structure in my js file:

```
$.getJSON("data/file.json")

.done(function(data) {
    var loadHTMLfunction =  /* some code */
    loadHTMLfunction();
    
    // updates display based on user filter selection
    $("#select-section").on("change", function() {
        $("article").find(".myClass").remove();
        loadHTMLfunction();
    });

    // text swap event
    $(".summary-link").on("click", function() {
        var el = $(this),
        tmp = el.text();
        el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
        el.data("text-swap", tmp);
    });
})

.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
     // error handling   
});
```

My issue is that my text swap event works well when the page is loaded for the first time but it doesn't work anymore once the user used the selection event (this event is a select html element to update display).

Is there something wrong in my js file structure or something wrong in my code (or in both!)?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't see your `loadHTMLfunction`, but my guess is that you are expecting the `click` Event to be bound to Elements that are not created yet. If that's the case put the `click` Event inside of a function that gets executed on page load and inside of `loadHTMLfunction`.

Comment: I am willing to make further improvements on my answer below if you can 1)Provide more information as to the DOM elements we're playing with actually is, and 2)Show what `loadHTMLfunction()` is. There really isn't enough information for a good answer to be made from this as of the moment.

Comment: The problem is that he binds click event once to ".summary-link"  but when the function loadHTMLfunction is called again the click event is not binded again. As I put in my answer event bind must be  in loadHTMLfunction after html creates.

Comment: @PHPglue The loadHTMLfunction() loads all my HTML on the page, including the element with the .summary-link class. I found event delegation to solve my issue. Do you find it a good alternative or should I go with your proposition? Thx!

Comment: If `loadHTMLfunction` loads "all" of your HTML, which may not really make sense anyways, then need to put all of your Events in there. The bottom line is that an Element has to exist at the time the JavaScript is written, unless your using an `onload` Event to wrap all of the code inside, or something Asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the coupling on your functions are too tight. Once `$.getJSON.done`, you should really just assign the data to a variable and bind your event handlers outside of your scope of the ajax call. A refactored version of the code might look something like this:

```
(function() {
    var storedData;

    $.getJSON("data/file.json", function(data) {
        storedData = data;
    });
    .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("error: " + textStatus + ", Description: " + jqXHR.responsetext); 
    });

    var loadHTMLfunction = function() {
        // your code
    };

    loadHTMLfunction(); // You ought to tell us what this function is
                        // else we don't know if it's redundant or not 
                        // to run so repetitively.

    $("#select-section").on("change", function() {
        $("article").find(".myClass").remove();
        loadHTMLfunction(); // I feel like this is an issue.
    });

    $(".summary-link").on("click", function() {
        var el = $(this),
        tmp = el.text();
        el.text(el.storedData("text-swap"));
        el.storedData("text-swap", tmp);
    });
}());
```

Answer (score -1):

You should include

```
// text swap event
    $(".summary-link").on("click", function() {
        var el = $(this),
        tmp = el.text();
        el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
        el.data("text-swap", tmp);
    });
```

in the function loadHTMLfunction.

```
loadHTMLfunction = function(){
    //your code
    // text swap event
        $(".summary-link").on("click", function() {
            var el = $(this),
            tmp = el.text();
            el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
            el.data("text-swap", tmp);
        });
}
```

You probably are doing some action that removes the element ".summary-link" and you  just bind  event first time.